# Using re.search in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

search so that I can extract the mac address of my device from a list of strings.
I need to match this device name:

```
Device 5: Broadcom Bluetooth Device (APPLE - 00:02:72:C7:EB:AC)
```

and I want to extract the bdaddress in the end, that is, `(00:02:72:C7:EB:AC)`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\(.* - (.*)\)')
```

This looks for anything in the format `(<characters><space><hyphen><space><string>)`. Since we are interested in the  we enclose that in parentheses to mark it as a group.

```
>>> string = 'Device 5: Broadcom Bluetooth Device (APPLE - 00:02:72:C7:EB:AC)'
>>> matches = re.search(pattern, string)
```

When you do a `re.search` on it it results in two groups:

- group 0 - (APPLE - 00:02:72:C7:EB:AC)
- group 1 - 00:02:72:C7:EB:AC

We are interested in group 1, so we access it as:

```
>>> matches.group(1)
'00:02:72:C7:EB:AC'
```